# Ubuntu - Can't install canonical-livepatch

Tags: 16.04, snap

I'm trying to install `canonical-livepatch`, but the installation hangs with the following error:

```
sudo snap install canonical-livepatch

error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Mount snap "core" (888) ([start snap-core-888.mount] failed with exit status 1: Job for snap-core-888.mount failed. See "systemctl status snap-core-888.mount" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
    )

systemctl status snap-core-888.mount

● snap-core-888.mount - Mount unit for core
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/snap-core-888.mount; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since gio 2017-02-09 11:02:02 CET; 6min ago
    Where: /snap/core/888
     What: /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_888.snap
  Process: 2861 ExecMount=/bin/mount /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_888.snap /snap/core/888 -t squashfs (code=exited, status=32)
```

Log:

```
feb 09 11:52:07 xxx.ip-xxx.eu mount[5781]: mount: unknown filesystem type 'squashfs'
feb 09 11:52:07 xxx.ip-xxx.eu systemd[1]: snap-core-888.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited status=32
feb 09 11:52:07 xxx.ip-xxx.eu systemd[1]: Failed to mount Mount unit for core.
feb 09 11:52:07 xxx.ip-xxx.eu systemd[1]: snap-core-888.mount: Unit entered failed state.
feb 09 11:52:07 xxx.ip-xxx.eu /usr/lib/snapd/snapd[937]: task.go:303: DEBUG: 2017-02-09T11:52:07+01:00 ERROR [start snap-core-888.mount] failed with exit status 1: Job for snap-core-888.mount failed. See "systemctl status s
feb 09 11:52:07 xxx.ip-xxx.eu /usr/lib/snapd/snapd[937]: taskrunner.go:353: DEBUG: Running task 161 on Undo: Download snap "core" (888) from channel "stable"
feb 09 11:52:07 xxx.ip-xxx.eu sudo[5691]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
feb 09 11:53:01 xxx.ip-xxx.eu CRON[5787]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
feb 09 11:53:01 xxx.ip-xxx.eu CRON[5788]: (root) CMD (/usr/local/rtm/bin/rtm 2 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null)
feb 09 11:53:01 xxx.ip-xxx.eu CRON[5787]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
feb 09 11:53:16 xxx.ip-xxx.eu sudo[5830]: xxx : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/xxx ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -xe
feb 09 11:53:16 xxx.ip-xxx.eu sudo[5830]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by xxx(uid=0)
```

How to solve?

Comment: Did you update your system first?

Comment: @George, yes, sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

Comment: Check the `journalctl -xe` to see what the problem is then!

Comment: @George I updated the question (xxx are private informations like ip relative to my server).

Comment: Do you still have this problem?